# O que é a arquitetura de Von Neumann?

Tags: memória, ciência-da-computação, arquitetura-computadores, teoria-da-computação

Como ela funciona e por que ela se tornou o modelo computacional dominante?

Comment: Sei que a arquitetura proposta pro ele é composta por memória, ALU e CPU, mas só isso rsrs. Boa pergunta!

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitetura_de_von_Neumann

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Não tem muito segredo nela, não é algo complexo, é o básico de tudo o que fazemos em qualquer atividade computacional, e só foi formalizado que seria assim que o computador deveria operar. Ela define que:

- há uma entrada de dados
- uma unidade que processa esses dados
- e provoca uma saída de dados
- o processador pode armazenar dados temporariamente em uma memória onde ficam instruções e dados puros

A entrada e saída pode contar com diversas formas. Conforme pode ser visto em [imagem da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture):

[image: Arquitetura Von Newmann]

Acredito que se tornou dominante porque foi uma das primeiras, é simples e intuitiva, faz muito sentido e atende bem todos os problemas. Talvez também porque ela não define muitos detalhes o que a faria ficar obsoleta rápido.

Outras arquiteturas podem optar por uma organização um pouco diferente, por exemplo separar a memória de instrução e de dados, pode tratar entrada e saída como algo diferente, pode fazer o tratamento de controle e cálculos de forma totalmente separada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Resumindo: posso dizer que é a arquitetura de um computador? Ou estou falando bobagem?

Comment: É a que todos adotam hoje. Poderíamos estar usando esta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture

Answer (score 6):

Resumindo o assunto a arquitetura é basicamente essa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em que se caracteriza em:

- Sistemas de entrada e saída;
- Memória Principal; e
- CPU(Processamento/Processador);

A memória principal funciona como um armário em que segura informações, tanto já na própria memória quanto novas que chegam dos sistemas de entrada e saída. A CPU fica encarregada de trabalhar(fazer cálculos) com todas essas informações, ficar trocando dados com a memória principal, e ao final se necessário mostrá-los nos sistemas de saída.

Penso que ela é a mais utiliza pois é um sistema simples, muito funcional e bem definido. Se não me engano, outras áreas da computação trabalham com arquiteturas um pouco diferentes, mas ela é uma grande referência.