# O que é a arquitetura de Harvard?

Tags: ciência-da-computação, arquitetura-computadores, teoria-da-computação

Lendo algumas coisas sobre arquitetura, em vários casos é comparado a Arquitetura de Harvard com a Arquitetura de Von Neumann. Encontrei aqui no SO essa pergunta sobre [O que é a arquitetura de Von Neumann?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189180/o-que-%C3%A9-a-arquitetura-de-von-neumann), mas não possui nenhuma citação ou comparação com a de Harvard.

Do que se trata a Arquitetura de Harvard? Como ela funciona? Quais vantagens ela possui em relação a arquitetura de Von Neumann?

Comment: Pode ser útil: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka3839.html

Comment: É tosco, mas é útil: na arquitetura de Von Neumann, dados e instruções são misturados. Na arquitetura de Harvard, elas ficam em cantos distintos.

Comment: Eu achava que a arquitetura de Harvard era a [Georgiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_architecture).

Comment: @Renan Está precisando de um emprego não?!  hahahaha trabalhar na praça é nossa. https://media.giphy.com/media/3oEduGOHIeikXrjRLi/giphy.gif

Comment: @acklay Acho que vai ficar só a minha mesmo :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Existem duas principais diferenças para a arquitetura Von Neumann:

- Código e dados são considerados coisas bem diferentes e são gerenciados separadamente, em locais diferentes.
- O controle da comunicação da arquitetura é central permitindo que as operações de comunicação sejam realizadas simultaneamente.

A separação de código e dados se mostrou pouco vantajosa e a simultaneidade foi obtida por outras formas na arquitetura Von Neumann, mais complexas, é verdade. Então ela nunca ganhou tração.

Hoje ela é usada em dispositivos muito específicos, em geral de forma híbrida. Um sistema de cache costuma parecer mais com Harvard do que Von Neumann. Cache L1 da Intel separa código de dados. Claro que o endereçamento é tratado de outra forma, mas como Von Neumann.

[image: Arquitetura Harvard]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).