# O que é a arquitetura de Cleópatra?

Tags: ciência-da-computação, arquitetura-computadores, teoria-da-computação

Existem várias arquiteturas básicas de computadores modernos. Aqui no SOPt possui algumas perguntas, sobre [arquitetura de Von Neumann](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189180/o-que-%C3%A9-a-arquitetura-de-von-neumann) e [de Harvard](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/217838/o-que-%C3%A9-a-arquitetura-de-harvard). Recentemente, em uma pequena leitura, citaram uma outra arquitetura, que seria essa tal arquitetura de Cleópatra(ou Arquitetura Cleópatra). Percebi que existiu o computador chamado *Cleópatra*, pelo que li em poucos coisas em português, então acabou me confundindo um pouco.

> *Trazer para a próxima aula o manual e o resumo da arquitetura
>   Cleópatra*. [Organização e Arquitetura de Computadores p.9/9](http://www.inf.pucrs.br/emoreno/undergraduate/CC/orgarqi/class_files/Aula17/Aula17b.pdf)

O que é a arquitetura de Cleópatra?

Comment: Pelo que eu achei nem é uma arquitetura no mesmo nível, é uma forma de implementação da Von Newmann, se não estiver enganado, não tem informação clara.

Comment: @bigown por isso que achei estranho e me confundi. A primeira dúvida foi qndo li em um slide que encontrei na internet sobre arquitetura de Harvard estava escrito: "Na próxima aula vocês trazem algo sobre a arquitetura de Cleópatra." Por isso fiz a pergunta.

Comment: http://www.inf.pucrs.br/emoreno/undergraduate/CC/orgarqi/class_files/Aula18

Answer (score 2):

Algumas universidades criam algumas arquiteturas para servirem como suporte no ensino de cadeiras de arquitetura de computadores. Essas são geralmente baseadas nas principais arquiteturas do mercado. A arquitetura Cleopatra é uma dessas, outros exemplos são Neander e Ramses.

Comment: Isso explica por que é tão difícil encontrar algo sobre essas arquiteturas.