# O que é o gargalo de von Neumann?

Tags: desempenho, arquitetura-computadores

De acordo com o que entendi da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture#Von_Neumann_bottleneck), o gargalo de von Neumann ocorre ao acessar grandes quantidades de memória ao mesmo tempo que ocorre algum mínimo de processamento desses dados por parte da CPU. A CPU tem capacidade muito maior de processar dados do que a taxa  de transferência de dados entre esta e a memória permitem ocorrer. Eu arriscaria dizer então que não é um gargalo que ocorre ou prejudica particularmente outras formas de processamento, por exemplo em situações de processamento intensivo de dados.

A imagem abaixo mostra a [arquitetura de von Neumann](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189180/357) com o gargalo decorrente  do único barramento (canal de transferência de dados) entre a CPU e a memória, que guarda tanto instruções como dados.

[image: Arquitetura de von Neumann, mostrando um barramento único entre a CPU e a memória.]

Por que a taxa de transferência entre CPU e memória principal engargala o processamento? No meu entendimento é porque o acesso à memória principal pela CPU é mais lento (mais distante) que aos registradores internos, e também porque o ciclo de busca e execução (*fetch-execute*) em uma arquitetura de dados e instruções compartilhados provoca isso, pois requer minimamente dois passos, um que é o acesso à instrução (cerca de três ciclos de *clock* de um total de, digamos, seis ciclos de *clock*, de acordo com a arquitetura von Neumann de 8 bits do livro *But How Do It Know?*, que de acordo com meu limitado conhecimento é bem minimalista) pelo mesmo barramento que fica ocupado para ajudar a operar a instrução em si, que é um passo que precisa ser feito em seguida e em separado. Por exemplo, para um cenário de adicionar R0 a R1 e armazenar em R0 temos o seguinte ciclo de busca e execução, e operações de *load* (da memória para o registrador interno) e *store* (do registrador interno para a memória) ocupam igual ciclo, trocando apenas os três últimos ciclos de clock:

- Ciclo de *clock* 1: IAR --> MAR (Move o endereço da instrução contido no registrador do endereço de instrução (IAR/PC) para o registrador de endereço da memória); ao mesmo tempo, já que IAR se encontra no barramento, incrementa IAR + 1 e o coloca no registrador acumulador ACC;
- Ciclo de *clock* 2: Move o valor em RAM para o IR (registrador de instrução);
- Ciclo de *clock* 3: Move conteúdo do ACC para IAR, efetivamente atualizando IAR/PC caso a instrução não cause um JUMP;
- Ciclo de *clock* 4: R1 --> TMP (move o conteúdo do registrador R1 para o registrador TMP, que é um dos operandos da ALU);
- Ciclo de *clock* 5: R0 habilitado no barramento + TMP --> ACC (a soma propriamente dita);
- Ciclo de *clock* 6: ACC --> R0.

Dessa maneira, uma transferência de dados em grande quantidade com um mínimo de processamento envolve por exemplo um conjunto elevado de operações de load/store, o que significa quatro acessos à memória por palavra (tipicamente um byte) trafegada (dois para o *fetch-execute* da operação de load, e dois para o *fetch-execute* da operação de store).

Tanto esse gargalo na busca e execução é provocado que ele é eliminado ou mitigado (coforme a definição de gargalo adotada) na [arquitetura de Harvard](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/217838/357), a exemplo da que é implementada no curso *From Nand to Tetris*, que utiliza dois barramentos e duas memórias, um para dados e outro para instruções, permitindo assim que ambas as classes de dados sejam acessadas ao mesmo tempo (embora o número de passos para o ciclo de busca e execução seja algo [entre dois e nove](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73594969/2241463)). A imagem dessa última arquitetura é reproduzida no final da pergunta.

**Minhas dúvidas são duas** (se a segunda atrapalhar ou tornar ampla leve em consideração somente a primeira, e a segunda poderá ser movida para outra pergunta):

- O gargalo de von Neumann é isso mesmo? Se não for, o que é?
- A arquitetura de Harvard possui esse gargalo, mitiga-o ou elimina-o? [Aqui](https://oskarth.com/nand-to-tetris-2/) diz que tem o gargalo. [Aqui](https://wiki.zacheller.dev/hardware/nand2tetris/computer-architecture) sugere, conforme o meu entendimento do gargalo, que o mitiga ou elimina. No meu entendimento apenas mitiga, pois apesar de ser mais rápido acessar essas informações ao mesmo tempo ainda permanece a lentidão motivada pela distância entre processador e memória.

Para referência, [pergunta](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/105712/126193) semelhante, se não idêntica, na comunidade de *Computer Science* da rede Stack Exchange. Indaga se o gargalo é a lentidão no acesso à memória e ao mesmo tempo um gargalo intelectual, ou se é devido ao compartilhamento entre dados e instruções. Não sei bem o que concluir dela com base nas respostas, pois uma diz que a maior preocupação no comentário do John Backus (reproduzido abaixo na tradução da Wikipedia) era a carga cognitiva para os programadores, e a outra diz que são ambas as razões citadas, mas mais a lentidão.

Apenas para eliminar uma outra possível confusão, ambas as arquiteturas são de [computadores de programa armazenado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored-program_computer#Description).

### Referências

Para completude, reproduzo abaixo, e tento traduzir em seguida, o trecho relevante da [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture#Von_Neumann_bottleneck).

#### Gargalo de von Neumann de acordo com a Wikipedia em inglês

> The shared bus between the program memory and data memory leads to the von Neumann bottleneck, the limited throughput (data transfer rate) between the central processing unit (CPU) and memory compared to the amount of memory. Because the single bus can only access one of the two classes of memory at a time, throughput is lower than the rate at which the CPU can work. This seriously limits the effective processing speed when the CPU is required to perform minimal processing on large amounts of data. The CPU is continually forced to wait for needed data to move to or from memory. Since CPU speed and memory size have increased much faster than the throughput between them, the bottleneck has become more of a problem, a problem whose severity increases with every new generation of CPU.
>
> The von Neumann bottleneck was described by John Backus in his 1977 ACM Turing Award lecture. According to Backus:
>
> *"Surely there must be a less primitive way of making big changes in the store than by pushing vast numbers of words back and forth through the von Neumann bottleneck. Not only is this tube a literal bottleneck for the data traffic of a problem, but, more importantly, it is an intellectual bottleneck that has kept us tied to word-at-a-time thinking instead of encouraging us to think in terms of the larger conceptual units of the task at hand. Thus programming is basically planning and detailing the enormous traffic of words through the von Neumann bottleneck, and much of that traffic concerns not significant data itself, but where to find it."*
>
> Mitigations
>
> There are several known methods for mitigating the Von Neumann performance bottleneck. For example, the following all can improve performance:
>
> - Providing a cache between the CPU and the main memory
> - providing separate caches or separate access paths for data and instructions (the so-called Modified Harvard architecture)
> - using branch predictor algorithms and logic
> - providing a limited CPU stack or other on-chip scratchpad memory to reduce memory access
> - Implementing the CPU and the memory hierarchy as a system on chip, providing greater locality of reference and thus reducing latency and increasing throughput between processor registers and main memory
>
> (...)
>
> As of 1996, a database benchmark study found that three out of four CPU cycles were spent waiting for memory. Researchers expect that increasing the number of simultaneous instruction streams with multithreading or single-chip multiprocessing will make this bottleneck even worse. In the context of multi-core processors, additional overhead is required to maintain cache coherence between processors and threads.

#### Minha tradução a partir da Wikipedia

> O barramento compartilhado entre a memória do programa e a memória dos dados leva ao gargalo de von Neumman, a limitada taxa de vazão (taxa de transferência de dados) entre a unidade central de processamento (CPU) e a memória, comparado à quantidade de memória. Dado que o único barramento pode apenas acessar uma dentre duas classes de memória por vez, a taxa de transferência é mais baixa que a taxa à qual a CPU pode trabalhar. Isto limita seriamente a efetiva velocidade de processamento quando se requer que a CPU execute mínimo processamento em grandes quantidades de dados. A CPU é continuamente forçada a esperar pelos dados necessários a serem movidos de e para a memória. Uma vez que a velocidade da CPU e o tamanho da memória aumentaram muito mais rápido que a taxa de transferência entre eles, o gargalo se tornou mais problemático, um problema cuja severidade aumenta a cada nova geração de CPU.
>
> O gargalo de von Neumann foi descrito por John Backus eu sua palestra no Prêmio Turing da ACM de 1977. De acordo com Backus:
>
> *"Certamente deve haver uma maneira menos primitiva de fazer grandes mudanças no armazenamento do que empurrando vastas quantidades de palavras de um lado para o outro através do gargalo de von Neumann. Não apenas é esse tubo um problema de gargalo literal para tráfego de dados, mas, com maior importância, é um gargalo intelectual que nos manteve presos a um pensamento de uma-palavra-por-vez em vez de nos encorajar a pensar em termos de unidades conceituais maiores da tarefa em foco. Com isso programação é basicaente planejar e detalhar o enorme tráfego de palavras através do gargalo de von Neumann, e muito desse tráfego diz respeito não aos próprios dados significativos, mas a onde encontrá-los."*
>
> Mitigações
>
> Há diversos métodos conhecidos para mitigar o gargalo de desempenho de von Neumann. Por exemplo, todos os seguintes podem melhorar o desempenho:
>
> - Fornecer um cache entre a CPU e a memória principal
> - fornecer caches separados ou caminhos de acesso separados para dados e instruções (a chamada arquitetura de Harvard Modificada)
> - usando algoritmos e lógica de predição de branch
> - fornecer uma pilha de CPU limitada ou outra memória de rascunho on-chip a fim de reduzir o acesso à memória
> - Implementar a CPU e a hierarquia de memória como um system-on-chip, fornecendo maior localidade de referência e assim reduzindo latência e aumentando a taxa de transferência entre registradores e memória principal
>
> (...)
>
> Em 1996, um estudo de *benchmark* de bancos de dados identificou que três de quatro ciclos de CPU eram gastos aguardando memória. Os pesquisadores esperam que aumentar o número de *streams* de instruções simultâneos com multithreading ou multiprocessamento em um único chip irão piorar esse gargalo. No contexto de processadores *multicore*, é requerido *overhead* adicional para manter a coerência de cache entre processadores e threads.

#### Arquitetura de Harvard do curso *From Nand To Tetris*

Imagem da arquitetura de Harvard do curso *From Nand to Tetris*, mostrando dois barramentos, um para instruções acessando a memória ROM e outro para dados acessando a memória RAM. O acesso a ambas é feito ao mesmo tempo.

[image: arquitetura do curso From Nand To Tetris, mostrando dois barramentos, um para instruções acessando a memória ROM e outro para dados acessando a memória RAM. O acesso a ambas é feito ao mesmo tempo.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sua questão parece focar na teoria e prática ao mesmo tempo, o que gera alguma confusão. Para responder acredito que será necessário separar essas dimensões.

### Na teoria

Para começar, vamos *desconsiderar* as velocidades relativas entre CPU e "memória". Sem essa preocupação, fica bem intuitivo afirmar que a arquitetura de Harvard (AH) não apresenta o gargalo *em relação* à arquitetura de von Neumann (AN), pelo simples fato que na AH:

1. A CPU tem linhas independentes de acesso aos dados e à memória;
2. O acesso independente elimina questões de acesso compartilhado, interrupções e outros degradadores de performance *em teoria*.

Ou seja, a CPU na AH consegue puxar dados *e* código ao mesmo tempo, ao contrário de uma CPU na AN.

Porém não é só o acesso é independente entre dados e código, mas também podem ser seus formatos, restrições, endereçamento, tamanhos de palavras... Tudo, enfim. O benefício teórico pode vir com custos associados. Ao permitir que dado e código sejam completamente separados, isso significa também que toda e qualquer divergência tenha de ser suportada e reimplementada. Em hardware, em software, e mais principalmente, em compiladores.

Mas a AH de não começou como uma questão teórica, ao contrário do que pode parecer pelo texto. Sua origem foi uma questão completamente prática, as [primeiras máquinas homônimas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) implementando a linha de código vinda de cartões perfurados e a memória de trabalho utilizando mecanismos eletromecânicos.

### Em 1977 a questão era outra

O artigo citado na questão fala especificamente do gargalo como sendo uma questão tão prática quanto intelectual. A questão prática segue abaixo, me desvio aqui para falar da questão intelectual.

A década de 1970 está tão distante da nossa realidade hoje que beira o impossível entender as preocupações da época. Nessa linha, gostaria de comentar uma passagem de *[The Mythical Man-Month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month)* que talvez ajude a entender o que o gargalo significava na época. O livro descreve como desnecessário a inútil, que o sistema operacional OS/360 desperdice a absurda quantidade de 26 bytes de código compilado para lidar com uma funcionalidade "menor", a saber, que o sistema operacional saiba lidar com anos bissextos.

26 bytes. O título da sua pergunta ocupa mais espaço que isso. E a mera presença desse espaço foi algo contencioso na criação de um sistema operacional comercial, onde anos bissextos existem, e, se não tratados corretamente, podem causar muitos problemas.

É nesse contexto que o gargalo de von Neumann se mostra estritamente relevante. A memória era extremamente limitada e lenta, *assim como os processadores*. Qualquer acesso aos dados *e ao programa* era lento, e isso tirava a noite de sono dos arquitetos e programadores, porque eles tinham que, manualmente, resolver essa questão de desperdício de CPU, muitas vezes tendo de escrever assembler pensando só nisso.

Outra questão a lembrar, também, é que os limitados recursos computacionais da época limitavam os compiladores. Alguns desses compiladores eram basicamente transcritores de texto para código, e não implementavam otimizações que hoje damos como certas, ou [que às vezes nos assombram](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBkNBP00wJE) em transformar o código numa coisa ininteligível, mas otimizada ao ponto do absurdo.

Essa preocupação que era quase exclusiva dos programadores hoje em dia está algo relegada aos compiladores.

### Na prática

Hoje em dia, os computadores gerais não são puramente Harvard *ou* von Neumann. Isso porque computadores otimizam a memória volátil em vários níveis de cache, os menores e mais rápidos perto do processador, os maiores e mais distantes entre a CPU e a memória RAM mais convencional.

Alguns desses caches são utilizados exclusivamente para alimentar a CPU com instruções, ou seja, são linhas de cache exclusivamente de código. Quando a CPU funciona alimentada por essa linha de cache, ele se comporta como na arquitetura de Harvard, e, quando por qualquer razão a CPU tem de executar instruções que não se encontram no cache, ele se comporta como uma CPU na arquitetura de von Neumann.

É preciso notar aqui, também, que as instruções que a CPU utiliza não são no geral homogêneas. Algumas instruções executam em um ou poucos ciclos, outras instruções precisam de dezenas a centenas de ciclos para executar.

Um computador na AH puro, que não tenha um cache line de instruções, vai processar *mais lentamente* que um computador que tenha um cache line de instruções, seja ele na AH ou AN. Isso é pouco intuitivo no geral, mas é possível observar que CPUs conseguem saturar as linhas de memórias em programas específicos, mas têm dificuldade de fazê-lo em situações mais gerais, justamente por conta da existência de instruções de processamento longo.

Essas instruções longas bloqueiam a CPU *e liberam as linhas de memória,* efetivamente permitindo que as linhas de cache trabalhem em paralelo. O que por sua vez permite que a CPU tenha disponível os dados em cache, que são mais rápidos que os dados na RAM (dado ou código).

Na arquitetura de von Neumann, esse mecanismo de *prefetching* é implementado uma vez só, num lugar só. Afinal, código e dados residem no mesmo lugar, numa memória só. Fosse uma arquitetura de Harvard, esse mecanismo teria de ser implementado em duplicado, em muito encarecendo o custo de processadores genéricos que, de qualquer forma, não conseguem saturar as linhas de memória ininterruptamente.

### Em resumo

1. O gargalo é mais ou menos isso mesmo, a existência de uma única linha de acesso a dados e código, sendo que a CPU precisa de ambos para funcionar;
2. Porém, os gargalos de 1970 (plural) são um pouco diferentes do gargalo de hoje (singular);
3. A existência, mitigação ou inexistência na prática do gargalo passa por questões de cache, *prefetching* e as instruções demoradas, algo eliminando a distinção entre existência e inexistência do gargalo, assim como a distinção entre arquiteturas.

#### Adendo

Pelos comentários, parte da questão é se o gargalo não ficou muito pior com o tempo, já que a velocidade relativa entre processador e memória aumentou muito. Parte da resposta está no fato de que as otimizações (memórias intermediárias, entre CPU e RAM, ou seja, os caches do processador) diminuem essa diferença, mas parte da resposta também está nas instruções de CPU mais demoradas.

Quando as instruções são rápidas, a CPU fica engargalada, sim. Porém essas instruções de CPU demoradas *executam muito mais, e muito mais rápido,* que o equivalente em instruções rápidas, porque elas não são demoradas de graça, elas fazem em hardware (que é rápido) o equivalente a muitas outras instruções equivalentes em software. Coisas tão básicas como [dividir e multiplicar](https://web.archive.org/web/20070524044410/http://www3.sympatico.ca/maury/other_stuff/atari_basic.html), que podem ser de [10 a 100 vezes mais lentas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174105/performance-comparison-of-fpu-with-software-emulation) em software que em hardware.

Se você olhar no assembly de 32/64 bits, verá várias instruções que têm somas e multiplicações no próprio assembly, direto na instrução. Muitas, na verdade. Coisas que uma CPU com instruções demoradas "faz por você", mas num assembly de 8 bits você de fato tem de fazer na mão.

Uma única instrução assembly matemática em uma CPU com FPU às vezes faz 50x mais coisas que o equivalente em instruções de 8 bits. Nessas horas, a CPU ser mais rápida que a memória é um benefício, porque daí essas 50x mais coisas em uma "instrução lenta" saem muito mais rápido que de fato fazer essas 50 coisas em instruções "rápidas", mas que estariam de qualquer forma engargaladas.

Comment: Vamos ver se entendi. Na teoria, descontando a distância relativa entre CPU e memória principal, não há gargalo na AH (a referência que citei dizendo que há gargalo então está incorreta, ou então considera a distância ao afirmar isso). A memória e o processamento eram recursos escassos (também eram gargalos na época de Backus, e a propósito acho curioso a Wikipedia focar em grandes quantidades de memória na sua definição, e também dizer que o gargalo aumentou com o aumento da velocidade da CPU, a meu ver apesar do número de interações aumentar também reduziu a "latência", digamos assim)...

Comment: ...e, na prática, considerando as distâncias relativas, é feita uma combinação das duas arquiteturas que reduz a relevância do gargalo (que hoje é um só, e que como entrou a distância na história presumo que se refira a esta e não ao gargalo do acesso compartilhado no barramento). No fim das contas, o que devo considerar que é o gargalo exatamente? Ou você quis dizer que isso tem pouca importância porque ele não é impactante hoje (o contrário do que a Wikipedia disse, mas entendo que ela disse isso deixando de fora otimizações)? Só para ficar claro na resposta.

Comment: O gargalo existe em máquinas com barramento único de memória, ponto. Isso é o gargalo. O cache apenas mitiga isso, às vezes ao ponto da irrelevância, pois diminui as distâncias entre memória e processador (distância física, distância de velocidades diferentes). O cache de instruções também diminui a diferença entre entre AH e AN. Wikipedia fala sim desses meio termos, ver *Mitigations* no artigo do gargalo.

Comment: Mexi um pouco na resposta, encaminhando esses comentários, de uma relida, veja se respondeu para aceitar.

Comment: Os parágrafos estão mais claros, mas nem precisava tanto. Obrigado por isso e por esclarecer sobre o gargalo. De acordo com o final do primeiro parágrafo citado do artigo da Wikipedia, com o aumento mais rápido da quantidade de memória e velocidade da CPU do que da taxa de transferência de dados o gargalo aumentou e aumenta em severidade a cada nova geração de CPU, sendo que, conforme você disse, com as otimizações isso não tem tanta relevância. Então acredito que ela afirmou isso sem considerar as otimizações. Foi isso que eu quis dizer.

Comment: Seria, talvez, então de mudar alguma coisa no texto da Wikipedia. Mas daí eu ofereço a perspectiva que talvez o texto lá seja com um foco mais histórico, falando primeiro do gargalo como ele era, e só mais ao final (e sem tanta ênfase) falando que ele não é tão preto no branco assim hoje em dia.

Answer (score -4):

É o que limita a taxa de transferência entre a CPU e a memória em comparação com a quantidade de memória. Está transferência é a menor taxa com que o processador consegue trabalhar e menor CPU seja forçado a esperar por dados que precisam ser transferidos para ou a partir de memória.

Comment: Quando copiar e colar algum material deixe o link da fonte http://cecead.com/assuntos/disciplinas/arquitetura-de-computadores/aula-03-arquitetura-de-computadores/#:~:text=de%20von%20Neumann-,Gargalo%20de%20Von%20Neumann,-O%20canal%20de . O autor da pergunta quer saber se o conceito apresentado na pergunta é o Gargalo de Von Newman(se não for refutá-lo) e também quer saber se a arquitetura de Harvard modificada possui esse gargalo, mitiga-o ou elimina-o?

Comment: @AugustoVasques me enganei sobre o "modificada", a arquitetura do curso Nand2Tetris é só de Harvard mesmo. Mais exatamente, _"historicamente chamada de arquitetura de Harvard"_ de acordo com o capítulo 5 do livro. Corrigi na pergunta.